# openFDA Device Adverse Events Data out of date

Tags: data-request, openfda

Does anyone know why the Device Adverse Events data available via the openFDA API has not been updated since 01-Jul-2015?

Answer (score 2):

My apologies, I posted a response earlier that was speaking about the status of the `/drug/event.json` API when your question is about the `/device/event.json`

The `/device/event.json` API is currently out of data due to some data corruption issues on the input data. We are currently working with the appropriate FDA folks to get this resolved. Until, it is resolved, we reverted back the last good copy of the device data that we had, which is from July of 2015.

Please keep an eye on the status page: https://open.fda.gov/api/status for updates.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I appreciate it.

You may know the answer to this too... I am using openFDA simply to determine the "mdrfoi__id" for an MDR that I need to build a direct URL link to a MAUDE database entry as in: http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfMAUDE/detail.cfm?mdrfoi__id=5043177 . Do you know if the "detail.cfm" script supports keys other than the mdrfoi_id?  Thanks for your thoughts....

Comment: I am not sure off the top of my head. I am only familiar with the raw MAUDE files, I have not used FDA database search tool that often.